# yii url manager with 2 params

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, yii-url-manager

I would like to create an url like this:
http://domain.com/index.php/hir/2015-02-12/news_title

Here is my urlmanager what doesn't work:

```
 'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array(
        'hir/<date:\d+>/<title:\w+>'=>'news/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
  ),
```

And here is my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to .htacces file, you can solve this by url-manager. Just change your first url-manager rule like this:

```
'hir/<date:\d+>/<title:\w+>'=>'news/view' TO 'hir/<date>/<title>'=>'news/view'
```

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL pattern is almost correct.

But `<date:\d+>` won't allow your date format (yyyy-mm-d). Because you gave Regex `\d`, which is shorthand for [0-9]. It wont allow  `hyphen sign` which is in you date string.

So, change the Regex, which can allow your date format.

I can suggest: Use `<date:[\w-]+>` instead of  `<date:\d+>` in your **urlManager**.